# How to compare Kusto query against 2 table columns?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

How do I check for a ProductLine whether 2 fields exactly match with 2 fields in dynTable?
Condition: IF PName matches with Name AND IF Cat matches with Category in dynTable

So basically we need to iterate through the items of dynTable with information from a table called  ProductLine.

```
| PName | Cat | Info
----------------------
| A     | X   | 123
| B     | Y   | 456
| C     | Z   | 789
----------------------
```

```
let dynTable = 
    print myDynamicValue = dynamic(
        [
        {
            "Name": "X",
            "Category": "Y"
        },
        {
            "Name": "A",
            "Category": "B"
        },
        {
            "Name": "A",
            "Category": B"
        }
        ]) 
    | mvexpand myDynamicValue 
    | evaluate bag_unpack(myDynamicValue);
dynTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `join` operator to join on both columns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

```
datatable(Name:string, Category:string)
[
    "X", "Y", 
    "A", "B", 
    "A", "B", 
]
| join (datatable(PName:string, Cat:string, Info:string)
[
    'A', 'X', 123,
    'B', 'Y', 456,
    'C', 'Z', 789,
]) on $left.Name == $right.PName and $left.Category == $right.Cat
```

Comment: I'm applying this to about >10000 records, is there perhaps a performance efficient way for this?

Comment: ~10K records isn't a lot. still, ideally - your data would be better structured before or at ingestion time, so that you don't have to expand dynamic arrays and use the `bag_unpack()` plugin on top of that, each time you run a query. you can look into using an ingestion mapping (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings) or an update policy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) to perform that transformation at ingestion time.